Terraform Azure Virtual Machine from Community images
I want to create a VM from a community image and can't find any information in https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm
can anyone share any information on how to create a VM from a community image.
This is what I tried so far, nothing seems to be working.
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "VM_nic" {
  name                = "VM-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.servers.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.servers.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.servers_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"


resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "BackBox_vm" {
  name                            = "BackBox"
  computer_name                   = "BackBox"
  location                        = azurerm_resource_group.servers.location
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.servers.name
  zone                            = "1"
  network_interface_ids           = [azurerm_network_interface.VM_nic.id]
  size                            = "Standard_D2s_v3"
  source_image_id                 = "/communityGalleries/BackBox-39ccaf4b-e81f-4250-a8f4-e32bc23a8312/images/BackBox"
  admin_username                  = "backbox"
  admin_password                  = "Passw0rd"

  disable_password_authentication = false

  os_disk {
    name                 = "os-disk"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
    disk_size_gb         = 128
  }
}


source_image_id or source_image_reference might be what you're looking for - see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine

source image id returns an error
Error: parsing segment "communityGalleries": parsing the CommunityGalleryImage ID: the segment at position 0 didn't match
│
│ Expected a CommunityGalleryImage ID that matched:
│
│ > /communityGalleries/myGalleryName/images/myImageName
│
│ However this value was provided:
│
│ > /CommunityGalleries/BackBox-39ccaf4b-e81f-4250-a8f4-e32bc23a8312/Images/BackBox
│
│ The parsed Resource ID was missing a value for the segment at position 0
│ (which should be the literal value "communityGalleries").
